# how to iterate through rendred widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 4 widgets named OptionCard (it's their Type) i'de like to iterate through them to check the value of their variables how can I do it ?

tried OptionCard.forEach but it doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Please provide more Information to your request...

Comment: I'm trying to check the state of each statefulWidget I have 4 instances of

Comment: You should at least supply the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way Flutter widgets are supposed to be used. Widgets (even StatefulWidgets) generally do not hold application state. They should only provide a view on state managed elsewhere.

There are many proven [methods of application state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) that are popular and well supported in Flutter.